# Most luxurious Bars/Lounges and overall night spots in South Africa

Tags: south-africa, nightlife, luxury

I'm looking to get information on the best and most luxurious nightlife spots throughout South Africa, places only the elite goes. As I'm not currently in the country would appreciate some local advice.

Comment: Could you narrow that down? Currently your question is rather broad - there are many, many cities in South Africa.  Perhaps you could indicate the cities you will be going to on your trip?